# Free CMS that allows user uploads

Tags: gratis, cms

I need a CMS, plugin (e.g., for WordPress), or even some PHP app. I want to create a simple website that allows users to upload files (savegames, for example). It should be easy to use, have categories, and require as few clicks as possible.

For example, something like these sites:

- https://nfc-bank.com (this is vBulletin which is too expensive for me)
- [GameFAQs saves](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gba/921905-pokemon-emerald-version/saves)

I've tried things like MyBB forums with Downloads plugin, but it does not work as expected: the user must provide an URL for the file instead of an upload button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drupal** allows this in a few simple steps, and gives you great flexibility to add new features in the future.

1. [Download](https://www.drupal.org/download) and [install](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/installation-chapter.html) Drupal 8.
2. Create a taxonomy vocabulary "Categories".
3. Create a content type "Savegame".

   1. Add a file upload field "Upload".
   2. Add a taxonomy term reference field "Category" and associate it with the vocabulary "Categories".
4. Edit the permissions to allow users to create a "Savegame" node.
5. Create a Views page that lists all nodes of the type "Savegame" (you can display it in a list, in a table, in a grid, and you can optionally group it by category, or have a filter for categories).

Clicks needed for a user:

1. Add new savegame
2. Use file picker to select the file
3. Hit publish button

Comment: Thank you. I've never used Drupal and just by following your steps I managed to almost do what I want.